# Unable to execute MPI programmes with MPICH mpirun installed with macports

Tags: macos, gcc, mpi, macports, mpich

While trying to execute MPI code written in fortran, I was prompted with error messages from mpirun. These messages occur even when calling mpirun without any arguments or executables. The errors are as follows:

```
[mpiexec@[host]] match_arg (utils/args/args.c:159): unrecognized argument oversubscribe
[mpiexec@[host]] HYDU_parse_array (utils/args/args.c:174): argument matching returned error
[mpiexec@[host]] parse_args (ui/mpich/utils.c:1596): error parsing input array
[mpiexec@[host]] HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (ui/mpich/utils.c:1648): unable to parse user arguments
[mpiexec@[host]] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:149): error parsing parameters
```

I'm running MacOS Mojave. My MPI installation is MPICH for gcc6 installed with macports.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled all MPI and gcc twice and obtain the same messages regardless.

Comment: And if you use `mpiexec` for launching your program ?

Comment: It seems to run fine using ```mpiexec``` which I suppose is a work around, but surely it doesn't explain why ```mpirun```  stopped working?

Comment: Please post your `mpiexec` command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of ‘which mpirun’ and ‘which mpiexec’? Just making sure they are both the one provided by the port...

Comment: I get the same for both, ```/opt/local/bin/```

Comment: Output of `stat -L /opt/local/bin/mpi{exec,run}` and `port installed mpich\*`? Do `mpirun --version` and `mpiexec --version` differ? (They shouldn't.) How about `port select --list mpi` ?  On the latest versions of mpich/hydra, mpiexec and mpirun are the same executable...

Comment: these are the outputs of ```stat``` :
 ```~> stat -L /opt/local/bin/mpirun
16777220 11908626 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root admin 0 582684 "Feb 13 16:26:09 2019" "Oct 14 17:23:44 2018" "Feb  5 17:04:12 2019" "Oct 14 17:23:44 2018" 4096 520 0x20 /opt/local/bin/mpirun``` its identical for both. I can't run ```mpirun --version``` it gives the same output as in the original question. ```mpich-gcc6@3.2.1_5+fortran (active)``` is the output of ```port installed mpich\*```

Comment: If you run `mpirun-mpich-gcc6 --version` (which is what `/opt/local/bin/mpirun` should point to provided you have done `sudo port select --set mpi mpich-gcc6-fortran`, do get the same error? I'll try to test on a Mojave system this evening.

Comment: Ive tried, and I don't get the same message using the full one, when I run that it tells me the version, 3.2.1